# Metal screw stuck in middle of deep plastic (resin) hole

Tags: screws, hanging, plastic

I was trying to tie something that has a deep hole (around 7 cm). I tried one screw that has stuck in the middle of the hole. I thought that the screw will come to the end but it didn't as its head is wider than the hole diameter. Now the screw's head is stuck in the middle of the hole while its tip is out of the other side of the hole. I can't get it out or push it further to the other side of the hole. This hole is a simple cylinder.

Any ideas how can I solve this situation? This thing I'm trying to hang on the wall is so important to me.

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: Are you saying you can see both ends? If so, you might get some movement by turning the tip manually with pliers (careful not to snap it off and lose that option). That might unstick the head enough to turn it the rest of the way. Have done this as a last resort.

Comment: I can see only the tip of the screw in the back-end of the hole. I also can see the head of the screw in the middle of the hole. I can drive the screw using a screw driver but it just spin but doesn't move forward or backward as the hole has no screw path (don't know the english word for it). I tried pushing the end of the screw to get it out of the hole but couldn't move at all.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What are you drilling this into (material, construction)? And, as @paul said, a picture would be worth quite a few words.

Answer (score 1):

I would push the screw out the way it went in. That is I would use something soft like a wooden dowel to push against the point of the screw. It may help to first drill a small pilot hole in the end of the dowel that the point of the screw can go into, then turn the dowel clockwise as you push it in. turning the dowel has a chance to turn the screw and this will help the screw head move out of the hole.

[image: pushing a dowel into hole]

Answer (score 1):

Before asking the question here, I asked it in 'crafts and art' Stackexchange website then someone told me it is not the right place so I deleted it and asked here. 
Before deleting it, someone genius suggested a very simple solution which is to put the plastic thing in very hot water, then it may become easier to push the screw out.
I have just tried it and it worked. 
So simple and yet works.